# Gitlab lab selective sign up

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I don't prefer to allow sign up to anyone in private gitlab instance until explicitly invited to projects in gitlab.

Is there any way to allow only those users to sign up to whom you send the invitation?

cheers,
ijaz

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sign up, but you (as admin) would have to sign them up.

I'm not aware of any e-mail invitation system.

Andres

Comment: yes you can invite users to your project , if if sign up is not enabled they will not be able to sign up and join . but if you enable sign up , everyone including those that are not invited , will be able to sign up which I dont want

Answer (score 0):

If you use [LDAP](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/auth/ldap.html) or [OmniAuth](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/omniauth.html), you can [block auto created users](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/user_management.html#maintain-tight-control-over-the-number-of-active-users-on-your-gitlab-installation), and then you'd have only need to unblock each user you would like to allow.
(Note: you'd have to configure [OmniAuth](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/omniauth.html) or [LDAP](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/auth/ldap.html))